# Hibernate-JPA inside Liferay Portlet

Tags: hibernate, jpa, liferay

I have to build a Liferay portlet & a Webapp(Spring REST app) both running on Liferay's tomcat bundle. Both will be using the same database to perform CRUD operations.

To achieve that I build a Hibernate + JPA data-layer(separate project as jar) which I can add to both project as maven dependency. I don't want to use Liferay's service builder due to project restrictions.

The data layer jar works fine in Spring REST app but the same is not working in portlet whereas portlet deploys without any error.

Only INFO I am getting in logs is:

**[QuerySplitter:114] HHH000183: no persistent classes found for query class: from className**

I believe somehow my portlet JPA connection is unable to read Entities as persistence classes.

Any suggestions & ideas will be helpful. Thanks in advance!

Data Layer Jar structure:

- src/java: All java files
- src/resource: META-INF/persistence.xml
- src/resource: META-ING/spring-config.xml (To create entity-manager, transaction, data-source.

Comment: Do you use spring-data in your portlet project?

Comment: @Tobias: No spring-data, Idea is to re-use data-layer code for portlet as well as web-app. Portlet will perform CRUD operation using the data-layer jar.

Comment: Could you show your query? It sounds like you are using `SELECT FROM xyz` while it should be `SELECT x FROM xyz x`.

Comment: @Tobias: no db call initiated, I checked mysql logs if query is generated or not. Although, I found a work-around after putting all the data-layer code in my portlet project. With this, the above error is gone and all hibernate calls were initiated. Strange but I really didn't understand the issue, just by putting the same code inside the portlet project & removing reference to jar made it worked.